# Support for analytical and navigation functions for Dataflow SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to get the FIRST_VALUE ever seen of an expression in my query, but it looks like the aggregate is not supported for HOP or TUMBLE. I also tried to do an OVER window, but that doesnt seem to work either.

Any recommendations on how to do this on Dataflow SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Apache Beam does not suppoort WINDOW functions via Calcite which is the default SQL dialect as mentioned here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/calcite/overview/

The other dialect that Apache Beam supports is Zeta and even there FIRST_VALUE is not yet supported as mentioned here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/zetasql/aggregate-functions/

The best option is to raise a feature request with Apache Beam or implement it by writing code using one of the language specific SDK's.

HTH